# What's the difference in counting up multiple columns in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I would like to count up multiple columns in an Oracle query. Apparently there's quite a difference in how you write it. These are the two possibilities I've tried:

```
select sum(column1 + column2 + column3) from ...
select sum(column1) + sum(column2) + sum(column3) from ...
```

The table is the same, the joins are the same, the where-clause is the same, etc. However when I run the queries, the first one results in 15,481.19 and the second query in 14,385.69. That's quite a difference...

I if export all the data to Excel and try to get a total of all values, the result is the same as the second query. In Excel I've tried adding them up in multiple ways:

- Just selecting all data
- Calculate the sum of each column and add them up
- Calculate the sum of each row and add them up

When I try in code to get all data and just add them up in code in stead of in the query, I also get the same result as the second query and as in Excel.

The problem is that the Oracle documentation says otherwise: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj13083.html. As you can see in this link, they say to use the first query.

FYI:

- The oracle client with version 12.1.0 was used for this.
- I tried it in both Oracle SQL Developer and in Toad.

Based on these tests, I now know that I need to use the second query to get the correct results, but I would like to understand why the first one gives a different result than expected. Does anyone have any experience with this? How is it possible that these queries return a different result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: the difference (most probably) stems from the fact that aggregate functions ignore NULL values.

So the query

```
select sum(column1 + column2 + column3) from ...
```

is equivalent to

```
select sum(column1 + column2 + column3) 
from ...
where (column1 + column2 + column3) is not null;
```

because the result of e.g. `1 + null` is `null`

but the query

```
select sum(column1) + sum(column2) + sum(column3) from ...
```

is equivalent to

```
select sum(column1) + sum(column2) + sum(column3)
from ...
where column1 is not null 
   or column2 is not null
   or column3 is not null;
```

Assuming the following data:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
--------+---------+--------
      1 |  (null) |  (null)
 (null) |       1 |  (null)
 (null) |  (null) |       1
      1 |       1 |       1
```

Then the query:

```
select *
from ...
where (column1 + column2 + column3) is not null;
```

Only returns the row with `(1,1,1)` and thus the result would be 3

But the query

```
select *
from foo
where column1 is not null 
   or column2 is not null
   or column3 is not null;
```

Returns all rows and thus the total sum is 6 (1 for the sum of the values from the first second and third row and 3 for the sum of the fourth row)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the effect of how null values are handled by the addition operator and the sum function. If a sum includes null values they are essentially ignored; but if you add a null to another number then the result is null. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators001.htm#SQLRF51152):

> If an operator is given a null operand, then the result is always null. The only operator that does not follow this rule is concatenation (||).

[and](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035):

> All aggregate functions except COUNT(*), GROUPING, and GROUPING_ID ignore nulls. You can use the NVL function in the argument to an aggregate function to substitute a value for a null. COUNT and REGR_COUNT never return null, but return either a number or zero. For all the remaining aggregate functions, if the data set contains no rows, or contains only rows with nulls as arguments to the aggregate function, then the function returns null.

You can see the effect with a dummy table:

```
create table t42 (column1, column2, column3) as
select 1, 2, 3 from dual
union all select 1, null, -3 from dual
union all select 1, null, 3 from dual;
```

Your queries get a similar effect:

```
select sum(column1 + column2 + column3) from t42;

           SUM(COLUMN1+COLUMN2+COLUMN3)
---------------------------------------
                                     12

select sum(column1) + sum(column2) + sum(column3) from t42;

 SUM(COLUMN1)+SUM(COLUMN2)+SUM(COLUMN3)
---------------------------------------
                                     10
```

If you do the column addition you can see why:

```
select column1, column2, column3, column1 + column2 + column3 from t42;

   COLUMN1    COLUMN2    COLUMN3                 COLUMN1+COLUMN2+COLUMN3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------
         1          2          3                                       6
         1                    -3                                        
         1          2          3                                       6
```

The second addition result is null, rather than -2. When that is summed with the two sixes the result is different to adding the summation of the individual columns.